# Table Gets Cut Off When Converting R Markdown to PDF

Tags: r, r-markdown

I am trying to convert a r-markdown file to pdf, and when I knit the file, the pdf contains tables with columns cutoff. The table is very wide; it has 27 columns. I tried removing 11 of the columns, but the table is still too wide.

I consulted this link: 
https://haozhu233.github.io/kableExtra/awesome_table_in_pdf.pdf

It's a great page on knitr::kable(). But, sadly, it did not solve my problem.

Here is the code I put together using the link above.

```
knitr::kable(table, caption = "My Caption", format = "latex", booktabs = T) %>%
  kableExtra::kable_styling(latex_options = c("striped", "scale_down"))
```

Because the table is sooo wide, the table is scaled down so much that the text in the table is too small to read. Any recommendations on what to do?

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: You might be able to use some Latex code to make the page landscape: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/308651/53880. You would need to load the package (which you can do with some of the options in the YAML header), and then wrap the section in `\begin{landscape} ... \end{landscape}` I think.

Comment: Actually it looks like `kableExtra` already has a `landscape()` function, which would make this much easier!

Comment: Yea, `landscape()` worked. Thanks!